# A series in terms of the Jacobi theta fuctions

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, theta-functions

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_series#As_theta_functions), one can find an expression of the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^pq^n}{1-q^n} 
$$
in terms of the Jacobi theta functions for $p=3,5,7$. I'm looking for an expression of this series for $p=1$.

Comment: I found the equality with $Constant \times \frac{\eta'}{\eta}$ where $\eta$ is the Dedekind function. But I don't know how to evaluate $\eta'$.

Comment: I suggest consult [OEIS sequence A006352](https://oeis.org/A006352) which includes  the formula "G.f.: $1 + 24 x d/dx(\eta(x))/\eta(x)$ where $\eta(x) = \prod_{n\ge1} 1-x^n$"

Comment: @Somos Yes, but it requires the derivative of $\eta$, and I don't know how to evaluate it. I found a (long) formula on Wolfram but it didn't work, oddly. Anyway I found a solution now :-)

Answer (score 2):

I found a formula, thanks to [this StackExchange answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89430/eisenstein-series-in-mathematica).

Denote by $E_2(q)$ the above series. Let $\tau$ such that $q = \exp(i\pi\tau)$. Let
$$
e_2(q) = \frac{6}{\pi} E(\lambda(\tau)) j_3^2 - j_3^4 - \theta_4(0, \tau) 
$$
where $E$ is the complete elliptic function of the second kind, $\lambda$ is the modular lambda function, and $j_3 = \theta_3(0,\tau)$.

Then $E_2(q^2) = e_2(q)$.

Answer (score 2):

You question is about the Eisenstein series $\,E_2.\,$ You asked

> I'm looking for an expression of this series

The doubt is about what "an expression" means here. It is already known that
$$ E_2(q) = 1 + \frac{24\, q}{\phi(q)} \frac{d \phi(q)}{dq} \qquad
\text{ where }\qquad \phi(q) = \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-q^n). $$

An expression using elliptic integrals and theta functions alone
based on a
[Mathematica SE answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/89430) is
$$ E_2(q) = (6/\pi)E(m)\,t_3^2 - t_3^4 - t_4^4
\quad \text{ where }\\ t_3 = \theta_3(0,q),\;t_4 = \theta_4(0,q),\;
m = 1-(t_4/t_3)^4. $$
My Mathematica function and code to check this expression is

```
EisensteinE2[q_] := Module[{t3, t4},
    t3 = EllipticTheta[3, 0, q]; t4 = EllipticTheta[4, 0, q];
    6/\[Pi] EllipticE[1 - (t4/t3)^4] t3^2 - t3^4 - t4^4];
With[{M = 10}, 
    (1 - Sum[24 DivisorSigma[1, k] q^(2 k), {k, 1, M}]) - 
    Series[EisensteinE2[q], {q, 0, 2*M}]]
(* O[q]^21 *)
```

---

**NOTE** carefully the `q^(2 k)` in the `Sum[]`. This is because
the nome $\,q = e^{\pi i \tau}\,$ is standard for Jacobi theta
functions $\,\theta_k(z,q)\,$ while $\,q = e^{2\pi i \tau}\,$
is standard for the
[Dedekind $\,\eta(\tau)\,$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function)
and [Eisenstein series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_series)
$\,E_{2k}(\tau).$

Comment: Thanks. I meant an expression that I can evaluate with a computer, in which I have an implementation of the Jacobi theta functions and the elliptic integrals. Your answer is basically the same as mine, but it is more self-contained, and there is a check in addition.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Thanks for your comment! You were not specific enough in your question. Note that my answer expresses $\,\lambda=m\,$ using theta functions avoiding the use of `InverseEllipticNomeQ`  and is similar to yours, but is an improvement.